# Is the phrase an idiom or a phrasal verb?

Tags: word-usage

[**Source**](https://m.facebook.com/pg/Ever-English-Magazine-363949173812760/posts/) *Ever English Magazine* (Facebook)

Here is a sentence in an article.

> Robots work on through the night while their human supervisors are at home in bed.

In the sentence, is the phrase 'are at home' an idiom or a phrasal verb? What does it mean?

Comment: I take it from an English Text, not from Ever English Magzine (Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

***[To be at home](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+at+home)*** is an idiomatic expression with the meanings listed below, but in your sentence its meaning is not idiomatic; it is literal and means that supervisors are in their houses, sleeping.

> - if someone is at home in a situation, they feel confident and happy because it is familiar to them and they know how to deal with it (often + in ) *By the end of the week she was beginning to feel more at home in her new job. He is equally at home in a symphony orchestra or playing jazz with friends.*
> - if something or someone is at home somewhere, they are suitable for that place and look right in it. *This painting would be more at home in an art gallery than hanging on someone's living room wall.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)